# хелп, помогите найти ошибку

Tags: java

здравствуйте есть код

```
private static BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
private static ArrayList<Word> set = new ArrayList<>();
private static Task01 t = new Task01();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Word f;
    while (true) {

        try {
            f = read();
            if (f.equals(t.new Word("")))break;

            uyuy(f);
            Collections.sort(set);
                for (Word l:set) {
                System.out.println(l.s + ": " + l.frequency);
            }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }

    }

}

public static void uyuy(Word f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {

        if (f.s.equals(set.get(i).s)) {
            set.get(i).frequency++;
        } else {
            set.add(f);
            break;
        }
    }
}

public static Word read() throws IOException {
    String s = reader.readLine();
    return t.new Word(s);
}
```

есть ещё класс Word в котором 2 поля : s - string и frequency-int;
задача состоит в том,что надо считывать с клавиатуры слова,чем больше одинаковых слов тем больше значение инта в ворде

1. почему в while не выводятся данные из листа?
2. когда делаю проверку в методе uyuy в коллекцию всё равно добавляются лишние элементы

---

помогите плииз)

Comment: как интересно.... завязано на класс Word, но именно его вы зажулили........ а `Debug`  еще не осваивали?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет

Comment: рекомендую.....отладка - важная часть при работе. чтоб не задавать миллион вопросов на ресурсах, а можно было самому посмотреть, что у вас лежит в переменных в процессе работы и быстро поменять всё самому

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо,буду пытаться разобраться с ним

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то должно быть так

```
public static void uyuy(Word f) {
  for (int i = 0; i < set.size(); i++) {
    if (f.s.equals(set.get(i).s)) {
       set.get(i).frequency++;
       return;  // если нашли слово, то выходим из метода
    }
  }
  // если мы дошли сюда, то во всей коллекции нет такого слова,
  // и мы его добавляем добавляем
  set.add(f);
}
```